# Thermal risks to other components when watercooling CPU

Tags: cooling, water-cooling, silent-cooling, cool-n-quiet

I recently ordered all the components for a new desktop system to replace my old, dying computer. I wanted to have a really quiet desktop, so I got a case rated for being quiet and opted to try a closed-system CPU water cooling kit (Antec Kuhler H2O 620) that was on sale for a very good price over the Thanksgiving weekend. Most of my components are still in transit, but I became somewhat worried when a friend mentioned that abandoning air cooling units can result in heat buildup inside the case due to heat generated by the video card and other components such as RAM, the northbridge, MOSFETs and voltage regulators radiating heat that the CPU fan would normally at least keep circulating around so it doesn't build up in localized areas.

Is this a realistic problem? What other precautions should I take to remove heat from other components? Adding more case fans seems like it would get really noisy. Are there quiet alternatives?

Comment: Does your case not have a fan?  The cooler you have purchased has a case mounted fan, which will get some airflow moving inside the case. You could add another 120mm fan to the case if you have room, these can be pretty quiet (compared to a cpu fan anyway - the bigger the fan, the easier it is to be quiet)

Comment: My case does have two 120mm low rpm intake fans at the front and one outgoing fan at the back.  It also has space to add up to two more on the side, but I'm hoping that won't be necessary.

Comment: Well that should be plenty.  You are dumping the heat from the cpu (which is a good portion of the heat budget) straight out of the case with the water cooler, so those fans will be pushing out heat from the other components - remember they are designed to push out the heat from the cpu as well.  You may well be able to turn off one or more of the intakes too.  You just need to monitor and tweak once you get set-up, but I would say you don't need to concern yourself with the cpu fan being absent, it wouldn't be contributing much to flow in this case anyway.